# Inheritable thread context with MockWebServiceClient

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run a multithreaded test for a web service using `MockWebServiceClient` but this fails because caching is configured with request scope via `@RequestScope` anootation.

This is the error I'm getting:

`Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.cacheManager': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`

Now, if I was using a `MockMvc` instead of `MockWebServiceClient` I think I could use `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilter(requestContextFilter)` and make the thread context inheritable.

This option however is not available for `MockWebServiceClient.createClient(wac)`.

Is there a way to make the thread context inheritable when using `MockWebServiceClient`? Or is there some other solution to my problem?

Comment: I think the use-case is a little strange. Integration tests are typically single threaded, because the services they interact with are stateless or only have state in the database (otherwise you would almost always have a race condition in a web scenario). Also even if you have a multi threaded test runs successfully it is no guarantee for the absence of error (that can only be done analytically, or by forcing the timing). Typically multi threaded test falls under the performance test domain, and are not run at mock level.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek Thanks for writing. I know it's not the typical case and we don't normally write tests like this either. However, I think I'm dealing with a race condition somewhere in the services and this seemed the quickest way to try and reproduce it. I won't take the absence of failure as a proof of correctness but instead planning to run it many many times hoping it will at some point fail.